# Change the color for first letter in a string php

Tags: php, html

I just learn PHP by myself so I have many things to ask. I read a sample code about how to change color for the first letter in the string but I don't understand what \1 in a span tag of HTML.I know it is used to change the color to red but why \1 but not another character. Really appreciate your help.

```
<?php
     $text = 'VietJack Team';  
     $text = preg_replace('/(\b[a-z])/i','<span style="color:red;">\1</span>',$text);  
     echo $text;
   ?>
```

Comment: Check the manual: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: I got it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use regex, and you shouldn't.

php have a native function called [substr_replace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php), and it gets the job done.

example :

```
<?php
    function str_replace_chr(string $str, int $position, string $format): string 
    {
        $chr = $str[$position - 1];
        $p1 = $position - 1;
        $p2 = $position - strlen($str);
        $replace = sprintf($format,$chr);
        return substr_replace($str,$replace,$p1,$p2);
    }
    echo str_replace_chr('VietJack Team', 1, '<span style="color: red;">%s</span>');
```

online eval : https://3v4l.org/hvv3p